# Create shared C object linked to Rust dylib for use in R

Tags: c++, c, r, rust, ffi

I am trying to create a shared object I can load into R that calls Rust functions by way of R's C API. To call Rust from C, I am following this [blog post](http://harkablog.com/calling-rust-from-c-and-python.html). My problem arises when I try to create the shared library and link to the Rust library. The linker complains that it can't find my Rust function. I am quite new to compiled languages and have given this a couple days' worth of effort before turning to SO. In that time I have learned a lot about compiler flags and yet come no closer to a solution. I think it may be something obvious.

My C++ code:

```
#include "Rinternals.h"
#include "R.h"
#include "treble.h"

// test.cpp
extern "C" {

SEXP triple(SEXP val) {

    int32_t ival = *INTEGER(val);
    Rprintf("9 tripled is %d\n", treble(ival));
    return R_NilValue;
}

}
```

treble.h:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t treble(int32_t value);
```

My Rust code:

```
#![crate_type = "dylib"]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn treble(value: i32) -> i32 {
  value * 3
}
```

This is what I'm doing on the command line:

```
$ rustc glue.rs
$ g++ -shared test.cpp -o test.so -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Headers -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Libraries -L. -lR -lglue
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "treble(int)", referenced from:
      _triple in test-dac64b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Inspecting the object file that rust creates:

```
$ nm -gU libglue.dylib
...
0000000000001750 T _treble
```

Comment: Try making a [MCVE](/help/mcve). For example, do you need to link against the R libraries to reproduce the error? I'd guess not.

Comment: If you want C code, why are you compiling as C++? Both gcc and Clang can compile as C, in which case there is no mangling without having to specify `extern`.

Comment: Mostly for my own learning. There is no reason for me to use C++, but that is how I started the project and I got to this point by making small edits. And now I am aware of name mangling!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the C++ code, you need to declare the Rust function (which is available via the C ABI) as `extern "C"`.

**treble.h**

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern "C" {
  int32_t treble(int32_t value);
}
```

The error you are getting is because the C++ compiler is *name mangling* the method `treble` before attempting to link against it. `extern "C"` disables the mangling.

Additionally, your Rust FFI code should always use the types from the [libc crate](http://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/libc/index.html); in your case you want `libc::int32_t`.

Comment: This indeed allowed me to compile successfully. I suspected it might have something to with mangling when the gcc version (stripped of the extern "C") worked. I am still having troubling loading the dynamic library in R, but  I'll save that for another question.